# Update div text (number) based on location of scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like the location of the scrollbar while I scroll down the page to be displayed in a id="num"

```
> var num = $(window).scrollTop();
> 
> $(window).scroll(function() {     
> $( "#num" ).text(num); });
```

Here is a simple fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Kx5Vj/1/

The zero shows up right when i first scroll, but then doesn't get updated.

Comment: $(window).on('scroll', function() { $( "#num" ).text( $(this).scrollTop() ) });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling it only at the beggining, you have to call it on every scroll:

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
    var num = $(document).scrollTop();
    $("#num").text(num);
});
```

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aWU2f/) with working demo. Also, maybe you will be interested in setting default value, but it can be easilly done with this at the beginning:

```
$("#num").text(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of `scrollTop()` changes as you scroll, so you need to get it each time the event is executed. Try this:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    var num = $(document).scrollTop();
    $("#num").text(num);
});
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/Kx5Vj/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `num` inside your `scroll` function so your `num` value can be updated each time scrolled:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var num = $(document).scrollTop();
    $( "#num" ).text(num);
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kx5Vj/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() { $( "#num" ).text( $(this).scrollTop() ) });
```